# How to format two separate lists in columns, rather than rows in Mathematica?

Tags: formatting, wolfram-mathematica

This seems like it should be a piece of cake, but I haven't found the answer in Mathematica's documentation. Say I have two separate lists, for example x={1,2,3,4,5} and y={1,4,9,16,25}. I want to format these lists as a table with each list as a column, like this:

```
x  y  
1  1  
2  4  
3  9  
4 16  
5 25
```

But if I do TableForm[x,y], I get only the first column, like this:

```
1  
2  
3  
4  
5
```

If I do Grid[{x,y}], I get a table, but formatted as rows instead of columns, like this:

```
1 2 3  4  5  
1 4 9 16 25
```

Now, if I have my values as {x,y} pairs, rather than separate lists, then I can get *almost* what I want,like so:

```
Input: Table[{n,n^2},{n,1,5}]//TableForm

Output:   
1 1  
2 4  
3 9  
4 16  
5 25
```

I say *almost*, because I'd like to have the variable names at the top of each column, and I'd like the columns justified so that the ones digits are always placed vertically in the "ones place", the tens digits in the "tens place", etc.

So, back to my question: If I have two separate lists of the same length, how can I format them as a table of columns? I checked the MMA documentation for Grid and TableForm, but I couldn't find a way to do it. Did I miss something? If there's no direct way to do it, is there a way to transform two separate lists into pairs of values that could then be formatted in columns using TableForm?

Thanks for any suggestions you might have.

Comment: Nevertheless you should select an answer, a task that many times requires explaining your choice. Read the FAQs. If you don't select one, you are implying that none answer satisfies your needs.

Comment: @belisarius Some how I missed your last comment until just now. I've have (belatedely!) selected a "best" answer. Nevertheless, I encourage readers of this question who are learning Mathematica to take a look at some of the other answers, as each will add something to your understanding of how Grid and Tableform work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Personally I prefer Grid to TableForm.  Maybe  something like this?

Some preliminaries:

```
x = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
y = {1, 4, 9, 16, 25};
grid = Transpose@{x, y};
headings = {{Item["x", Frame -> {True, True}], 
    Item["y", Frame -> {True, False}]}};
```

The following code,

```
Grid[Join[headings, grid], Alignment -> Right, Dividers -> All, 
 Spacings -> {3, 1}, FrameStyle -> Orange]
```

gives this as output, for example:

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Often in Mathematica, you use [Transpose](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Transpose.html) to switch the role of row and column.

```
In[6]:= x = {1,2,3,4,5}; y = {1,4,9,16,25};

In[7]:= {x,y} // Transpose // TableForm

Out[7]//TableForm= 1   1

                   2   4

                   3   9

                   4   16

                   5   25
```

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using `Transpose` you can use the option `TableDirection`:

```
x={1,2,3,4,5};y={1,4,9,16,25};
TableForm[{x,y},TableDirections->Row,TableHeadings->{{"x","y"}}]
```

[image: a table without legs, but with a head]

Comment: Thanks Simon. I wasn't even aware of the TableDirections option.

Answer (score 3):

```
 Grid[Transpose[{x, y}], Alignment -> Right]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I would use:

```
x = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
y = {1, 4, 9, 16, 25};

TableForm[{{x, y}}, TableAlignments -> Right]
```

[image]

---

Here are some more convoluted examples, demonstrating the way TableForm works.  It does get complicated, and I usually have to experiment a bit to get what I want.

```
a = {1, 2, 3};
b = {4, 5, 6};

{a, b} // TableForm
```

[image]

```
{{a}, {b}} // TableForm
```

[image]

```
{{{a}}, {{b}}} // TableForm
```

[image]

```
{{{a}, {b}}} // TableForm
```

[image]

```
{{List /@ a, List /@ b}} // TableForm
```

[image]

```
{{a}, b} // TableForm
```

[image]

```
{{{a}, b}} // TableForm
```

[image]

```
{{{a}}, {b}} // TableForm
```

[image]

```
{{{{a}}, {b}}} // TableForm
```

[image]

Comment: Nice! I was able to get it right-aligned as follows: 

TableForm[{{x, y}},TableAlignments->Right]. 

Question: Why does adding an extra pair of parentheses switch the output from rows to columns?

Comment: @belisarius I guess I failed to comprehend that requirement.    @eipi10, TableForm flips the direction at each level of the data.  Is it appropriate to edit my post to add examples?

Comment: I'm relatively new to stackoverflow and am not sure of site etiquette, but I would certainly like to see your examples.

Comment: @eipi10 examples are already up.  If any one of them is too confusing I will do my best to explain why it does what it does.

Comment: @Mr. Editing your answers for providing a better understanding and/or corrections is encouraged.