# Wolfram Mathematica 9.0 Generate vertical table

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I'm new in system Wolfram Mathematica 9.0 and I want to make table with horizontal approaches. And I had made only vertical ones. Now I will show you:

[image: Here is the output+ code]

Comment: Try `TableForm[{{4, 16}, {3, 5}}, TableHeadings -> {{"x", "y"}, None}]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did not show the input that produced the undesired output, but I assume it is something like this:

```
xx = {4, 16};
yy = {3, 5};

TableForm[{{xx}, {yy}}, TableHeadings -> {{"x", "y"}, None}]
```

To get the output you desire you merely need to leave out the extraneus set of `List` brackets (`{}`) around each expression.  You can also omit `None` as this is inferred.

```
TableForm[{xx, yy}, TableHeadings -> {{"x", "y"}}]
```

[image]

You could also expressly specify the directions with `TableDirections`:

```
TableForm[{{xx}, {yy}},
  TableHeadings -> {{"x", "y"}}, 
  TableDirections -> {Column, Row, Row}
]
```

This earlier answer of mine illustrates the way that `TableForm` formats nested lists:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5011242/618728

Comment: @Gary You're welcome.  If you have more questions I suggest you ask them on [Mathematica.SE] (the dedicated Stack Exchange site for *Mathematica*).